What is happening to AskUbuntu main site?
Since yesterday, https://askubuntu.com/ is in read only mode most of the times. Any idea about the problem and why it is not resolved yet?

clearing all my cookies seemed to work - seems something fishy with a non SE cookie that makes it look read only

Thanks. I haven't met a similar problem during my 5+ years usage before.

Nuke your browser cache completely.  This was already stated by someone else, and a browser cache erasure solved the problem.  This includes cookies, clear them and then login again fresh and it should be resolved.
